# Should dconf-service start at boot?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, dconf

I've recently had some problems when I tried to install the latest gnome-shell and then revert back to the stable version.  After I purged all the PPAs that I was using and reinstalled gnome-shell and everything, I found that things still weren't working quite right.

I found somewhere online (obviously a reputable source) that deleting my dconf config files from  `~/.config/dconf/` and `~/.cache/dconf/` and then rebooting would help. While that did reset all my gnome-shell settings back to initial (like I wanted), I discovered another problem in that I could not change any settings on my system, via `gnome-tweak-tool`, `System Settings`, or `dconf-editor`. I would receive an error message of :

`WARNING **: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name ca.desrt.dconf was not provided by any .service files`

After much googling and fiddling, I was able to figure out that I could change settings if I ran `/usr/lib/d-conf/dconf-service &` and then changed all my settings while it was running.

I have two questions:

Would anyone know why something like this would happen (and is there anything I can do to fix it?

and

Is it terrible to add `/usr/lib/d-conf/dconf-service/` to my startup applications so I'm able to change settings while using my computer day-to-day? This is really just a workaround, but I want to know if it's safe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that ca.desrt.dconf.service is missing from /usr/share/dbus-1/services/ . Try reinstalling dconf-gsettings-backend. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks so much! For some reason ca.desrt.dconf.service was missing. Any idea why? Reinstalling that package in Synaptic seemed to fix it though. Thanks again!